# Querying Data from Room Persistence Library within RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to query specific data from within my recyclerview. I attached an image to show what the item of the recyclerview is. I currently used a nested child recyclerview for the image, but I don't mind if I have to use a textview and stringbuilder. I've been formatting my data accessing using this [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0) which focuses on MVVM. Basically in the image, for that specific exercise, there will be associated details that I query with an input.

[image]

The issue is, I'm trying to query data within my recyclerview to get the specific exercise details, but I do not know how. As you can see, the repository and room database requires an application to call the methods, but I do not know how to implement that within the recyclerview adapter in the onBindViewHolder.

LogAdapter.java

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LogHolder holder, int position) {
        LogEntity currentLog = getItem(position);
        holder.tvExerciseName.setText(currentLog.getExerciseName());
        long exerciseId = currentLog.getId();

        // I want to use exercideId as a query

        }
    }
```

LogRepository.java

```
public LogRepository(Application application){
        LogDatabase db = LogDatabase.getInstance(application);
        logDao = db.logDao();
        addTypeDao = db.addTypeDao();
    }
...
    public LiveData<List<AddRepsWeightsEntity>> getLogsRW(long id){
        return addTypeDao.getLogsRW(id);
    }
```

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface AddTypeDao {
    //RW
    @Insert
    void insertRW(AddRepsWeightsEntity addRepsWeightsEntity);

    @Update
    void updateRW(AddRepsWeightsEntity addRepsWeightsEntity);

    @Delete
    void deleteRW(AddRepsWeightsEntity addRepsWeightsEntity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM AddRepsWeightsEntity WHERE logId = :logId ORDER BY id ASC")
    LiveData<List<AddRepsWeightsEntity>> getLogsRW(long logId);
```

If this is not a very good practice, I would really appreciate it if someone suggested a better solution. I've only been learning android studio for a few weeks now and this is the only thing I could think of. Thank you!

Comment: So whats the problem, where is this exercise Id, that you need for the query?

Comment: In the lag adapter on bindviewholder. The long ecerciseId is the filter I want to query with but I don't know how in in the recycler view adapter